# IntelliSense: too few arguments in function call

Tags: c++

I am writing a program for a class that takes the amount of a sale and computes the change from a dollar. Each denomination is listed with the amount of coins as the output. I am unable to run it due to an error with too few arguments?

I am not sure what VB is looking for here. Any help would be appreciated.

Program code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

// Determines how many of each coin to dispense.
void Dispenser(int, int *, int *, int *, int *);                                    



int main(void)
{
    // Change the console's background color.
    system ("color F0");

        // Declares the variables.
        double amount_paid = 1.00, amount_due;                                                             
        int amount_left, dollar_qty, quarter_qty, dime_qty, nickel_qty, penny_qty; 

    // Get user input.
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "Enter the money amount paid: $";
        cin >> amount_due;
    cin.ignore();

    // Perform calculations.
    amount_paid = amount_paid * 100 + 0.5;
        amount_due = amount_due * 100;

        amount_left = amount_paid - amount_due;
        dollar_qty = amount_left / 100;

        Dispenser (amount_left + quarter_qty + dime_qty + nickel_qty + penny_qty);

        "\n";


        // Display output.
        cout << "\nAmount of the purchase: " << fixed << setprecision(2) << showpoint        << amount_due;
        cout << "\nChange from $1.00: " << fixed << setprecision(2) << showpoint <<      amount_left;
        cout << "\n" << fixed << setprecision(2) << showpoint << dollar_qty << "      dollars";
        cout << "\n" << fixed << setprecision(2) << showpoint << quarter_qty <<       "quarters";
        cout << "\n" << fixed << setprecision(2) << showpoint << dime_qty << "dimes";
        cout << "\n" << fixed << setprecision(2) << showpoint << nickel_qty <<      "nickles";
        cout << "\n" << fixed << setprecision(2) << showpoint << penny_qty <<      "pennies";

    system("pause");
        return 0;   
}

void Dispenser(int amt_left, int *quarters, int *dimes, int *nickels, int *pennies)
{
    int    total_change, total_quarters, total_dimes, total_nickels, total_pennies;

    // Determine change amount by quantity.

    total_change = amt_left % 100;
    total_quarters = total_change / 25;
    total_change = total_change % 25;
    total_dimes = total_change / 10;
    total_change = total_change % 10;
    total_nickels = total_change / 5;
    total_change = total_change % 5;
    total_pennies = total_change;

    *quarters = total_quarters;
    *dimes = total_dimes;
    *nickels = total_nickels;
    *pennies = total_pennies;
}
```

Error is on this line at the ")"

```
Dispenser (amount_left + quarter_qty + dime_qty + nickel_qty + penny_qty);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dispenser (amount_left + quarter_qty + dime_qty + nickel_qty + penny_qty);
```

Should be

```
Dispenser (amount_left, &quarter_qty, &dime_qty, &nickel_qty, &penny_qty);
```

Comment: The base function is expecting a memory address, and & sends that address to the function instead of the value of the variable.

Answer (score 5):

```
Dispenser (amount_left + quarter_qty + dime_qty + nickel_qty + penny_qty);
```

Should be

```
Dispenser (amount_left, quarter_qty, dime_qty, nickel_qty, penny_qty);
```

Your version really is just one big parameter adding up all the values, whereas the one I provided, with the commas, means it's 5 separate parameters being sent across to the function.

Answer (score 2):

You used a '+' instead of ','?